Gap in a statically indeterminate problem
How to solve problem, if we don't know $\Delta$.
Prior to loading, a gap exists between the column face and the absolutely rigid plate .

Find the allowable value of the gap $\Delta$ from the strength condition;
Draw the epuples $N$, $\sigma$, $w$ after loading.

Parametrs of problem:
$F = 25$ kN, $l_1 = 200$ mm, $l_2 = 200$ mm, $l_3 = 100$ mm, $E_1 = E_2 = E_3 = 200 000$ MPa, $A_1 = 100$ mm$^2$, $A_2 = 200 mm^2$, $A_3 = 100$ mm$^2$, $\sigma_{fluidity} = 300$ MPa, $[n] = 2 = \frac{\sigma_{fluid}}{\sigma_{max}}$


epuples -> epures

Cutting and pasting Russian text can lead to this.

It is a springs in series problem. If the gap is too large the column will fail at a stress of (2*sigma_fluid). I think that's enough clues for this rather homework looking problem.
